# Как найти первый пиксель равный 1 в битовом изображении через Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

Есть изображение из 1 и 0, надо найти первый пиксель равный 1 и покрасить его в черный(или любой другой цвет).

```
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp1.Height - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp1.Width - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (bmp1.GetPixel(i, j).G == 1)
                    {
                        bmp3.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 255));
                    }
                    else j=j+1;
                    control.textBox12.Text = Convert.ToString(j);
                }

            }
```

Comment: `Есть изображение из 1 и 0` А можно спросить, этокак?

Comment: Массив, где значение пикселей может быть либо 0, либо 1.

Comment: `bmp1.GetPixel(i, j).G == 1` Ну, вы проверяете зеленый канал цвета. Только цвет в данном случае задается от 0 до 255. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color